# Disabling areas on Credential Provider

Tags: c++, windows, credentials, credential-providers

I'm working on a credential provider for windows 7 with cpp. I want to disable textboxes and submit button while the system is working in the background. For this I tried to use the code below:

```
_pCredProvCredentialEvents->SetFieldInteractiveState(this,SFI_EDIT_TEXT,CPFIS_DISABLED);
```

At here `SFI_EDIT_TEXT` represents the object that I want to change it's properties and `CPFIS_DISABLED` shows it's should be disabled (at least i assume that is). But I didn't get any useful result. Anyone can able to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a several situations, where using `SetFieldInteractiveState` won't work. For example, if user have pressed "Submit" button, your's provider `GetSerialization` function will be called, and no GUI changes will be done by LogonUI until you return from `GetSerialization`. I think changes of GUI are made only between calls of your provider's functions.

P.S. I know, that question was asked long time ago, but in future, maybe, my answer can help others.

Comment: where would i put the logic if i want to show a PinCode text field with a submit button after user hit the submit button?